# How to open a popup window with custome length and width size in Spring MVC Projects using Javascript, Ajax, and Java with JSP file?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to open a pop-up window with custome length and width of the window by using Javascript, Ajax on JSP.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in my Spring MVC Project by the following way:

The **Controller class** is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "viewPicture.dispatch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewPicture(HttpServletRequest request, RequestParam(value="fileName")String fileName, @RequestParam(value="filePath")String filePath) {

    //some code..

    return "viewDCPicture";   //the View where it will go.
}
```

The **JSP page** on which I have written JS and Html code also, is like this:

```
<script>
    function viewDCPicture(fileName){
        var filePath = $("#filePath").val();

        //Setting the left and right size of the pop-up window
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(1100/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(170/2);

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url : "viewPicture.dispatch?fileName=" + fileName + "&filePath=" + filePath,
            success : function(response) {
                var strURL = "viewPicture.dispatch?fileName=" + fileName + "&filePath=" + filePath + "";
                window.open(strURL, 'viewDCPicture', 'width=1100, height=600, resizable=1, scrollbars=yes, location=0, status=0, titlebar=no, toolbar=0, addressbar=0, top='+top+', left='+left+'');
            },
            error : function(e) {
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label>SUPPORTING DOCS.</label></td>
        <c:forEach items="${attachmentDtlList}" var="data"> 
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Picture" onclick = "viewDCPicture('${data.key}');">${data.key}</a>
                <input type="hidden" id="filePath" value="${data.value}">
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my **template.xml** where the JSP files are mapped with the perticular `name = "viewDCPicture"`, I have made changes like this:

I have created a template inside the template.xml file as:

```
<definition name = "viewDocTemplate" template = "/viewDoc.jsp">
    <put-attribute name = "body" value = "" />
</definition>
```

And used it inside the temlate.xml file as:

```
<definition extends = "viewDocTemplate" name = "viewDCPicture">
    <put-attribute name = "body" value = "/enquiry_management/viewDCPicture.jsp" />
</definition>
```

The **viewDoc.jsp** file which will help the **Pop-up window** file **viewDCPicture.jsp** to bind it inside body of **viewDoc.jsp** is as follows:

```
<%@ page language = "java" contentType = "text/html; charset = UTF-8"
pageEncoding = "UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix = "tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix = "spring"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%-- Adding spring attribute for adding body, header, footer etc tag. --%>
    <spring:htmlEscape defaultHtmlEscape = "true" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name = "body" />
</body>
</html>
```

The **viewDCPicture.jsp** file is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <table align="center" class="headingSpas">
        <tr>
            <td class="headingSpas">
                <table width="100%" align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="headingSpas" >
                            <img alt="" src="<%=path%>" border="0" align="top" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```